# Mobile Accordian Menu Not Working in 1.9.2.3

Tags: navigation, mobile, topmenu

For some reason my Mobile Menu is no longer working. The Main Link "Collection" does expand and open, however, all other sub links don't expand.

Not sure where to look to fix. Website is http://www.jennyyoo.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see its a CSS issue. You need to add this to your CSS file after where the ul is set to display none.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 770px)
    .nav-primary li.level0 li.menu-active ul {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

I have tested this. See image blow

[image]

Comment: Colin you are amazing! This worked! Thanks so much!!

Comment: Hi Elva, No problem at all :)